# Specify JDK for tomcat7

Tags: java, bashrc, jdk, tomcat

I have installed `tomcat7` (using `apt-get install`) and whenever I want to start `tomcat7` it says :

```
* no JDK found - please set JAVA_HOME
```

I have set `JAVA_HOME` in my `bash.bashrc` and also in `~/.bashrc` and when I issue `echo $JAVA_HOME` I clearly see that this variable is pointing to my jdk's root folder. Can someone help me with this please?

Thanks

Comment: This helped me to find where I can tell `tomcat7` what JDK to use.

Comment: Same here. Now I know where tomcat looks for JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can try this:

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/tomcat7
```

When the file opens, uncomment the line that sets the JAVA_HOME variable.

[image]

Save and restart tomcat7 server.

Comment: Note that upgrading to JDK 7 will break this answer. Using a symbolic link without the version number will allow upgrades without invalidating environment variables.

Comment: Also works for `tomcat8`, just replace `tomcat7` strings by `tomcat8`.

Answer (score 9):

Tomcat will not actually use your JAVA_HOME environmente variable, but look in some predefined locations and in the JAVA_HOME variable set inside the startup script, as other answers point out.
If you don't like messing with the tomcat startup script, you could create a symlink for your preferred java installation, which will be picked up by tomcat.

For example:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
```

Comment: This conflicts with package `default-jre-headless`

Answer (score 5):

Open terminal

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Copy the result. Then

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tomcat7
```

Replace `#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-6-jdk` with the output you copied from `$JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add following line in /etc/default/tomcat7 at where JAVA_HOME variable is defined

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

then run command

```
sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer of Mitch (the accepted answer above), check your `/usr/lib/jvm/` directory. Usually, java is installed there itself.

You might have oracle java installed or you might have a latest version of java installed. Just checkout the directories at `/usr/lib/jvm/` and add the one your java is in.

For me, it was:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

So, replace

```
#JAVA_HOME=/some/directory
```

with

```
#JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

did the job for me.