# Set java version on Ubuntu server

Tags: 14.04, java, environment-variables, update-alternatives

I have java version 6,7,8 installed on my Ubuntu server, the result of `update-alternatives --config java` is

There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing `/usr/bin/java`).

```
  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java   2         manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

I tried [How to set the default Java version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308663/how-to-set-the-default-java-version/498227#498227) to set my current java version.
when I do `java -version` I am getting:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

which is correct but at runtime I getting the version as

```
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre
```

which is the result of

```
System.out.println("Java Home: "+System.getProperty("java.home"))
```

How do I set java7?

Comment: How do you start the Java program that prints the wrong home? Assuming you start it in a terminal somehow, what is `$JAVA_HOME` in that terminal?

Comment: Java program is a web application and the statement gets printed after deploying the app in the container and making the request to the resource which contains the print statment.

Comment: and $JAVA_HOME is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Open /etc/environment and manually set the JAVA_HOME Directory.

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

In your case to set Java 7 add the following line in /etc/environment

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre"
```

Then update the source by executing the following command:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: I am using bashrc to set the Java home and after setting the Java home here I used source command to reload the changes but no luck

Comment: Are you trying to run Java from terminal or any third party applications like eclipse??

Comment: this http://askubuntu.com/a/154967/201077 resolved my issue